# HTTP Method 'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are POST,DELETE,GET,HEAD

Tags: salesforce, apex, workbench

I have created a method to update the records in a case.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping= '/FieldCases/*')
global with sharing class RestCaseController {
    @HttpPatch
    global static String caseUpdate(String caseId, String caseStatus, String caseNote){
        Case companyCase = [SELECT Id, Subject, Status, Description FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseId];

        companyCase.Status = caseStatus;
        companyCase.Description += caseNote;
        update companyCase;

        Return 'Updated';
    }
}
```

and in work bench I am using

/services/apexrest/FieldCases

```
{"caseId" : "0037F00000bQYIjQAO",
 "caseStatus" : "Working",
 "caseNote" : "updating from the work bench"}
```

but I am getting the below error

HTTP Method 'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are POST,DELETE,GET,HEAD

Comment: Surely that patch should be to the individual resource, `/FieldCases/0037F00000bQYIjQAO`?

Comment: thank you so much for responding, I have tried this one but the error is still the same :(

Comment: Did you try to use Postman? Just to make sure you don’t run into a workbench snag?

Answer (score 0):

It worked alright for me. Here's a screenshot of the request in workbench:

[image]